# A more secure way to persist entity key in an edit view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I always have misgivings about just storing an entity key using a hidden input in my views. It's only too easy for even a curious user to edit this value in a browser console, and possibly end up updating an entity to which that user shouldn't have access.

Is there a feasible way to persist this value in views without adding too much complexity with encryption etc?

Comment: [This article](http://blog.slatner.com/2010/01/20/SecuringFormValuesInASPNETMVC.aspx) discusses one method of preventing tampering of hidden fields, but in any case you should be checking if the user has permission to edit/access the entity in the controller

Comment: If you're that concerned about somebody tampering with a hidden field, then you could put it in the `Session`, then on post check the posted value matches with the `Session` value. As @StephenMuecke said though, if your security needs to be that tight then permissions to edit at this level should be checked in your business logic.

Comment: You should not rely on any type of obfuscation or validation on client side. The only solution is to validate that current user has all the permissions to edit the posted entity.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a javascript variable. Then on postback create a js function and make the most suitable use of it in there (if you use AJAX postbacks  it should be easy ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 methods :

```
1st for Encryption
2nd for Decryption
```

(Or you can make single method with combination of encryption and decryption based on parameter)

```
So, encrypt you query parameters in your GET Method. 
And decrypt you query parameters in your POST Method.
```

You also can make Custom `ActionFilterAttribute` to decrypt your encrypted query parameter.
There are also more ways to handle this but this is too simple to implement as first step.

Example :

```
public enum EncryptType
{
   ENCRYPT,
   DECRYPT
};

public string EncryptDecrypt(EncryptType encType , string strtext)
{
            string result = string.empty;
            if (encryptionType == EncryptType.ENCRYPT)
            {
                 result = //Do Encryption on strtext
            }
            else if(encryptionType == EncryptType.DECRYPT)
            {
                result = //Do Decryption of strtext
            }
            return result;
}
```

Comment: simple and best as a first security step.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all input from the client is modifiable by the client, and should be treated as untrusted.

Even if you encrypt, hash & store the hash in session or otherwise obfuscate the id values, you still aren't dealing with access control properly.

If a different user was to obtain the obfuscated value by any means, and then submit that valid value with their own credentials/cookies, how would you process it?

If you don't check that the logged on user is allowed access to the specified resource at the point they make the request, then your application is still open to abuse.

How big is the overhead in obfuscating the value vs performing an access control check? Not so much in hardware performance, but the mental load of developers, debugging, code review.